# Define in typescript object type to contain a specific property key

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a Ionic Sqlite database helper library and to ease the work on the rest of the functions, I would need to require the user to have the ID key on the Params property along side his other keys.

```
   interface dbObj {
      tableName: string;
      orderBy: string;
      Params: paramsList;
    }
```

The Params property should require to have the ID key in it, but should not interfere with any other keys the user might add after in the Params.

```
interface paramsList {
    ID: string;
    ????
}
```

How do I enforce having the ID key in Params but let the user freely add any other key in paramsList?
I hope this does not sound stupid since I'm still new to typescript.

Comment: Read about [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) and how to get around them, specifically the sentence saying "a better approach might be to add a string index signature"

Comment: like @jcalz said you can have an interface with a defined property and a string index signature. This would assume that all the other properties are strings. 

        interface paramsList {
            ID: string;
            [property: string]: string;
        }

Comment: Yes. Thank you soo much!

Comment: @Xenos does my answer help to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
   interface dbObj {
      ...
      Params: {ID: string, [key: string]: any};
    }
```

Now `Params` is forced to have `ID` and it also can contain any other field.